# CASE STATEMENT ELSE THEN EQUAL TO THE DATA INSIDE THE COL

Tags: oracle, case

My sample table is below:

```
TASKMASTER
TASKKEY  TASKCOLTYPE01 TASKCOLDATA01
  001           1          DONE
  002           2           2
  003           3           3
```

TASKCOLTYPE values: 1 = text, 2 = yes/no, 3 = high/mid/low

I have a case statement:

```
SELECT TASKCOLTYPE01, TASCOLDATA01, CASE TASKCOLTYPE01 = 2
  THEN CASE TASKCOLDATA01 =1 THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO
  CASE TASKCOLTYPE02 =3
  THEN CASE TASKCOLDATA01=1 THEN 'HIGH WHEN TASKCOLDATA01 =2 THEN 'MID' ELSE 'LOW END
  ELSE (RETURN the value itself)
END FROM TASKMASTER;
```

I would like to show the data col in the table ('DONE' in this example)

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this helps.

```
  drop table TASKMASTER;
Create table TASKMASTER (
  TASKKEY VARCHAR2(3)
, TASKCOLTYPE01 varchar2(255)
, TASKCOLDATA01 varchar2(255)
);
insert all 
  into TASKMASTER (TASKKEY, TASKCOLTYPE01, taskcoldata01) values (001, 1, 'DONE')
  into TASKMASTER (TASKKEY, TASKCOLTYPE01, taskcoldata01) values (002, 2, 2)
  into TASKMASTER (TASKKEY, TASKCOLTYPE01, taskcoldata01) values (002, 2, 1)
  into TASKMASTER (TASKKEY, TASKCOLTYPE01, taskcoldata01) values (003, 3, 1)
  into TASKMASTER (TASKKEY, TASKCOLTYPE01, taskcoldata01) values (003, 3, 2)
  into TASKMASTER (TASKKEY, TASKCOLTYPE01, taskcoldata01) values (003, 3, 3)
select * from dual;

SELECT TASKCOLTYPE01, TASKCOLTYPE01, TASKCOLDATA01,
        CASE 
          when TASKCOLTYPE01 = 2
          THEN  (CASE when TASKCOLDATA01 =1 THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' end)
          when TASKCOLTYPE01 = 3
          THEN (  CASE  when TASKCOLDATA01=1 THEN 'HIGH'
                        WHEN TASKCOLDATA01 =2 THEN 'MID' 
                        ELSE 'LOW' 
                  END)
          ELSE ( Taskcoldata01)
        END result
FROM TASKMASTER;
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer would be

ELSE TO_CHAR(USERTASK.TASKCOLDATA01)

Its will return the value in the table field.

Hope its help!